# ArcMap MXD and its published REST service have different results when queried

Tags: arcgis, arcmap, arcgis-server

I have a point feature layer with attribute count 290.

When I perform query on the basis of particular column eg: `select * from PWS_Point where districtname='HINGNA' AND assettype='Borewell'` the result obtained in an MXD is 8.

Now I perform same query on the REST service published from this MXD, the result I get is 8 at first, but after refreshing the page or doing the same query again I get a different result.

I have tried the following with no success:

1. Recreating mxd
2. Republishing the service
3. Published the service on different server
4. Increasing the count number

What am I doing wrong or what is making the difference in count?